# How can set currency after price in hybris?

Tags: currency, sap-commerce-cloud, price

I want to show the prices as 45.99 Kč
It is showing as Kč 45.99.

I tried formatters.impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE PriceFormatter;owner(CountryConfiguration.code)[unique=true];patternPositives[lang=cs_CZ];patternNegatives[lang=cs_CZ];decimalSeparator[lang=cs_CZ];groupingSeparator[lang=cs_CZ];currencySymbol;
;CZ;#{groupingSeparator}##0{decimalSeparator}00 {currencySymbol};- #{groupingSeparator}##0{decimalSeparator}00 {currencySymbol};,;space;Kč;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find PriceFormatter in version 2005.Can it be custom type which is developed by your team?

Currency position information coming from localization. You can check `DefaultPriceDataFactory` class. It is determine current locale with `CommerceCommonI18NService` and `I18NService` then determine format in `createCurrencyFormat` method.

I am not sure CZ currency format but you can check it in your/server NumberFormat localization. If your java localization not mach your need, you can change it.

Another way is editing `price.tag` file for frontend to change using `price` and `currency` instead of `formattedPrice`.